# Probabilities from Classification Models give probabilities to only 1 decimal place

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability

I am running a basic classification on a dataset. My problem is that sometimes the target_probabilities are only given to 1 decimal place. This seems to be random, e.g. sometimes they are given to several decimal places. Note that this doesn't just happen for the Bagging Classifier - it appears to occur for several Classifiers.

Here is the code below, with output.

```
train = df[df['Season']<2018] 
test = df[df['Season'] == 2018]

X_train = train.drop([target,'Season','Team'],axis=1)
X_test = test.drop([target,'Season','Team'],axis=1)
Y_train = train[target]
Y_test = test[target]

model = BaggingClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_predicted = model.predict(X_test)

target_probabilities = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
target_probabilities = np.clip(target_probabilities, a_min=0.05,a_max=0.95)
print(target_probabilities)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this is a problem. Does it affect the classification performance of your models?

Comment: Is this the code you are really using? Is it possible that the returned probabilities are form the voting of the n classifiers? If you have 20 in total 1/20 would yield the 0.05 and 19/20 would yield the 0.95.

Answer (score 1):

You got 1 decimal because `BaggingClassifier` is averaging results of all estimators' **predictions** inside. By default, your estimators are `DecisionTree`s, `n_estimators=10`.

So, your prediction from DT is binary (either 0 or 1), BC summarizes them and divides by the number of estimators. That's why you get 1 decimal.

If you put `n_estimators=10000` you get a more precise number.

> Note that this doesn't just happen for the Bagging Classifier - it appears to occur for several Classifiers.

Which Classifiers have you tested? For LogisticRegression everything works as expected.